# numpy time series data - vectorized fill gaps and calculate deltas

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I've read some data in from csv using `genfromtxt` and `hstack` to concatenate the data which results in a shape of `(5413260,)` (it takes about 17min, ~1GB .npy save file)

The data is in the format:

```
timedelta64 1, temp1A, temp 1B, temp1C, ...
timedelta64 2, temp2A, temp 2B, temp2C, ...


>>> data[1:3]
array([ ('2009-01-01T18:41:00', 755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
       ('2009-01-01T18:43:45', 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1)],
      dtype=[('datetime', '<M8[s]'), ('sensorA', '<u4'), ('sensorB', '<u4'), ('sensorC', '<u4'), ('sensorD', '<u4'), ('sensorE', '<u4'), ('sensorF', '<u4'), ('sensorG', '<u4'), ('sensorH', '<u4'), ('signal', '<u4')])
```

I'd like to do deltas on the temps:

```
timedelta64 1, temp1A - temp1B, temp 1B - temp1C, ...
```

and fills:

timedelta64 2 - timedelta64 1 <= sample rate, otherwise fill with a stub with the appropriate time stamp:

```
timedelta64 1 + shift, 0, 0, 0, CONSTANT, ...
```

I'm currently:

1. iterating through the numpy arrayA (arrayA[i], arrayA[i+1])
2. calculate the delta for row_i, append to numpy arrayB
3. calculate the time difference between row_i+1 and row_i
4. iteratively add to shift to timestamp, fill with zeros/constant, append to numpy arrayB

This is highly inefficient - its taken over 12 hours so far and I expect it will take ~ 100+ days to complete.

Whats the vectorized approach?

I'm thinking a vector op to calculate the deltas first, then I'm not sure how to quickly batch and insert the fills for the missing timestamps.

Also, is it faster to reshape -> diff -> fill or reshape -> fill -> diff?

Aside: this is for pre-processing data for machine learning with tensorflow, is there a better tool than numpy?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using `genfromtxt` and heterogenous `dtypes`, vectorized operations are accomplished through named columns: [to slice columns in a tuple present in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134724/to-slice-columns-in-a-tuple-present-in-a-numpy-array)

Generating a range of numpy.datetime64: [How can I make a python numpy arange of datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137277/how-can-i-make-a-python-numpy-arange-of-datetime)

Concatenating large arrays in numpy is slow, its best to use pre-allocated array and fill in using slices: [How to add items into a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064822/how-to-add-items-into-a-numpy-array/5068182#5068182)

Then how to merge two structured / record arrays based on matching datetime64 and masking the appropriate fields. Which is found here: [Compare two numpy arrays by first Column and create a third numpy array by concatenating two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600823/compare-two-numpy-arrays-by-first-column-and-create-a-third-numpy-array-by-conca)

Overall speedup looks like 100+ days => <5 min (28,800x faster). The pre-allocated array should also speed up loading from csv.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer. Additional information about your question should be add to the question itself.

Comment: Its most certainly the answer short of copy and pasting all the code which is unique to my data. I hope the information I've gathered here will be helpful to others new to numpy experiencing difficulty pre-processing time series data.